# PHP creating multidimensional array errors

Tags: php, arrays

I want to create a multidimensional array on my code. I wrote something like below:

```
$game[$game_id]['map'][$place][0]
```

But I'm getting these errors:

-Illegal string offset 'map'

-Uninitialized string offset

-Undefined offset

Last 2 errors are for $place.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You cant create the whole array in one step.

You get these errors, because `$game[$game_id]` seems to be an string and not an array. So `['map']` tries to accesss the 'map' index of an string which causes the *Illegal string offset* warning. The other errors are just an result of this, because `$game[$game_id]['map']` returns *null*(and the warning)

```
$game = array(
    $game_id => array(
        'map' => array(
            $place = array(...)
        )
    )
);
```

This should work